# templatetag to display list on individual rows

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm struggling to get my templatetag to work. I believe it's the syntax or the way i'm calling app_filters. Forgive me i'm learning web application development so if my logic is off please correct me. My goal is to pass a collection of check boxes on one template to a new one filtered at a different level report_id is the collection of each check box.

I have an array in my view from my GET.getlist call below

```
checkedlist = request.GET.getlist('report_id')     
reportlist = QvReportList.objects.filter(report_id__in= checkedlist, active = 1).values_list('report_name_sc',flat = True)

print (checkedlist)
print (reportlist)

args = {'retreivecheckbox': checkedlist}

return render(request,'accounts/requestaccess.html', args)
```

When I print my array the console displays it correctly, this example is if there was two check boxes selected:

```
['88', '89']
<QuerySet ['Common Data Model Reconciliation Load', 'LEJR BPCI IV - ICS Baseline']>
```

I've created the following templatetag called app_filters defined as:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_list(querydict, itemToGet ):

    return querydict.getlist(itemToGet)
```

Now i'm trying to get my template to display what's in my console but as individual rows/indexes dependent upon user selections. I'm told get_list will do that for me. I've also tried get_at_index. I.E. I want to see retreivecheckbox as

```
88

89

and not [88,89]
```

Using the following template my app prints correctly, however, all on one row as 88 89.

```
{% for app in retreivecheckbox %}
{{ app }}
{% endfor %}
```

When I try several variations of the following my template displays nothing. Why doesn't my get_list break my array into indexed lines?

```
{% load app_filters %}

{% for app in retreivecheckbox|get_list:report_id %}
{{ app }}
{% endfor %}
```

My book example shows it as

```
{% for app in retreivecheckbox|get_list:"report_id" %}
```

However, when I use double or single quotes it gives me the following error:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'getlist'
```

Using `{{ request.GET|get_list:"report_id" }}` prints the list out as [88,89] [88,89]

I've tried all sorts of different variations, but its not displaying as I want it to or it won't display.  I've been trying print '\n'.join(map(str, list_of_ints)), it works except the 4 items is still one check box, instead of 4.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you have a querydict here. You don't, you have a plain list. And the reason it displays on a single line is that HTML ignores line breaks; you need explicit HTML tags, for instance `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Daniel for his clarification, this was easily solved by using list tags in HTML.  I was over thinking the problem.